# How do I find the first 5 files in a directory with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, file, sorting, glob

How would I list the first 5 files or directories in directory sorted alphabetically with PHP?

Comment: Do you need them to be *the first 5 when sorted according to <name/size/date>*, or just any 5 files?

Comment: No-one who creates a nice `glob` answer, using a pattern to filter out directories?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Using `scandir()`:**

```
array_slice(array_filter(scandir('/path/to/dir/'), 'is_file'), 0, 5);
```

The `array_filter()` together with the `is_file()` function callback makes sure we just process files without having to write a loop, we don't even have to care about `.` and `..` as they are directories.

---

**Or using `glob()`** - *it won't match filenames like `.htaccess`*:

```
array_slice(glob('/path/to/dir/*.*'), 0, 5);
```

---

**Or using `glob()` + `array_filter()`** - *this one **will match** filenames like `.htaccess`*:

```
array_slice(array_filter(glob('/path/to/dir/*'), 'is_file'), 0, 5);
```

Comment: Perfect, Is there a way to sort the files by date?

Comment: This is a useful old thread. But when apply array_filter it won't work in php 7.0

Answer (score 1):

It's probably most simple to use `scandir`, unless you want to do something a bit more complex. `scandir` returns directories as well, so we'll filter to only allow files:

```
$items = scandir('/path/to/dir');
$files = array();
for($i = 0, $i < 5 && $i < count($items); $i++) {
    $fn = '/path/to/dir/' . $items[$i];
    if(is_file($fn)) {
        $files[] = $fn;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$i < 5` should be replaced with `count($files) < 5`

Comment: Should it? `$i < 5` and `count($files) < 5` are pretty much the same, although `$i < 5` would be marginally faster as it doesn't call a function

Comment: $i is also 5 when 5 directories are found... And the OP wants files

Comment: No need to loop there... Check my answer.

Comment: @Alix in your answer, what happens if there is a directory (other than `.` and `..`)?

Comment: @adam: Nothing, the directories are ignored due to the usage of the `array_filter()` function in combination with the `is_file()` function callback.

Comment: ...which was added after my last comment

Comment: @adam: No, don't make me a liar: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8dec8230-025c-4bfa-9132-87c96cfbb5d2/view-source this is my first post, `array_filter()` with `is_file()` is there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking low level (ordered by inode number), then [readdir](http://www.php.net/readdir) is the function for you.

Otherwise, if you want them alphabetical, then [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) might be a better option. As in:

```
$firstfive = array_slice(scandir("."), 2, 5);
```

Note that the first two entries returned by `scandir` are "." and "..".

Comment: I like scandir. But doesn't that scan all the files in a directory?