# Showing specific image from folder

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to insert a specific image from a folder on to my `products`. But with the code I have now, it displays all the images from the folder on all the products. How do I only show 1 specific image per product?

```
$dir = "pictures/productimg/";
if ($opendir = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($opendir)) !== false) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            echo "<div class='productimg'>";
            echo "<img src='$dir/$file'/>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are doing here. How is your code selecting a specific image file for a specific product? It just seems to be selecting all files within a directory! Do the image files have the product ID in the file name? Where are your products stored?

Comment: You are using `readdir`, it will loop through all file in dir, so what is your actual problem?

Comment: @Ally that's my problem.. I don't to select all, but only 1 image to show on 1 element. So:
image 1 goes to product 1
image 2 goes to product 2
And not:
image 1+2 goes to product 1
image 1+2 goes to product 2

Comment: @Ally They do not have the product ID, and the products are stored in a database

Comment: @zerovacpls Does database store file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the image file name in the database (recommended) with a relationship to the product, assuming you may want to have multiple images for each product (recommended), you would create a new table e.g. `product_images` with fields `product_id` & `file_name`, creating a foreign key on `product_id` to point to the product id e.g. `products.id`. Now you can simply get the images for a product by doing `SELECT file_name FROM product_images WHERE product_id = xx`, then check the file exists within the image directory and if it does, pull the image by it's name which is now known, because you fetched it from the database.

EDIT: Also note you should ensure file names are unique, and the best way to do that is to include the product ID in them or at least a micro time stamp.

Tip: If one entity is going to belong to another e.g. an image belongs to a product, you should almost certainly use the database for storing that relationship. It will make everything so much easier, logical and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
array_slice(glob('/path/to/dir/*.*'), 0, 1);
```

See [How do I find the first 5 files in a directory with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113565/how-do-i-find-the-first-5-files-in-a-directory-with-php)